# Does a didLostPeripheral (or similar method) exists in CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

Does a `didLostPeripheral` method, the opposite of `didDiscoverPeripheral:`, exist in CoreBluetooth? A method that is called when peripheral stops advertisings. I am quite sure that the answer is **no** but I would rather be wrong than sorry. I didn't find any mentions of anything like that in `CBCentralManagerDelegate`.

**Motivation**
The idea is to be able to maintain a list of *active* peripherals advertising a specific service

**Post Scriptum**
I was hoping to find a delegate method similar to [NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnetservicebrowserdelegate/1412917-netservicebrowser?language=objc), found in [NSNetService](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnetservice?language=objc), but that's a different framework with a different purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspect, the answer is “No”. If you are connected to a peripheral then you will get a `didDisconnect` delegate callback when a peripheral goes out of range.

If your app is running in the foreground then you can use the `allowDuplicates`  scanning key to receive advertising packets repeatedly. You can then maintain your own list of peripherals that you have seen.

The general algorithm would be something like:

- when a peripheral is seen (`didDiscover`) add it to the list, if not present and set the age to 0
- Each second iterate over the list, incrementing the age. Remove any peripheral whose age is, say, 5

Comment: Thats works if the scanning device is in FG. It doesn’t work in BG. Alternative solution would be to make the scanning device call the scan method every second or so. That would work in background.

Comment: You can't really perform a scan every second or so in the background; there isn't a supported background execution mode that would allow that.  There isn't really a solution available for the background, but you wouldn't typically need one.